# Import ASP.NET Page to Existing ASP.NET Project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and I was asked to create a portal program which will be just a part of the existing ASP.NET portal project. Meaning, it will be just like 2 web pages and will be going to be added to the existing project. The thing is I have to do it in a separate ASP.NET Project file. I have the source code of the existing main project but I am not allowed to modify this unless the pages that I will develop are completed. How can I do it? I know I just have to create a new project but what is the next step after that? How can I import the one that I made to the main project? They mention that I just have to export it as DLL but I have no idea how to do that. Please help me.

Comment: I would hope that whomever you're doing this for has some sort of version control, which means you should just be able to work off of a fork or branch of the master project. Whenever you've completed your work and had it approved, you would either create a pull-request (assuming Git or Mercurial) or be given commit access. There's no reason to create a separate project.

Comment: @TiesonT. The reason for this kind of approach is there are others who also are working on different features of the main portal. so whenever we have completed the works given to us, we will just have to import it to the main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your new project in Visual Studio.
2. Open the old project in Visual Studio.
3. Right click the name of your new project on Solution Explorer, select Open Folder in File Explorer
4. Copy the 2 new pages you created
5. Go to the Visual Studio Instance of your old project. Click the name of the solution and CTRL + V or Right Click > Paste. (If there is a folder let's say Pages where ASPX files are located, click and paste there instead).
6. Your new files might not be included in the project and if its happens, click the 'Show all Files' option on the Solution Explorer.
7. Right click on the 2 new ASPX files and select 'Include In Project'.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is kind of guidelines is what I need. I will note this one. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you right. If you just have to export the dll from the project that you created, right click on your solution, open the bin folder, you will see a file named yourprojectname.dll. Copy this to your target projects bin folder using the steps mentioned above.

If I understood it right, you are being asked to created a classlibrary or something and not an aspx page. Again, I might be wrong, but others can help you if you are lucid about your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't  know that DLL file is auto generated. I thought I have to do another process. Thank you. But I really need to create new aspx.